# Using Cavalieri to derive a formula for $n$-dim $L^p$ ball

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

let $p>0$ and $B_p^n:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : |x_1|^p+\cdots + |x_n|^p\leq 1\}$. Show that $B_p^n$ is Borel-measurable with $$\lambda^n(B_p^n)=\frac{(2\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{p}))^n}{\Gamma(1+\frac{n}{p})}$$

**My idea:**

I have a hint saying that I have to look at the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-(|x_1|^p+\dots+|x_n|^p)}\mathrm{d}\lambda^n(x)$. I know that I could just use power laws and fubini to achieve a gaussian integral that I could compute. But I have to use Cavalieri's principle.

I started like this: We have:$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-(|x_1|^p+\dots+|x_n|^p)}\mathrm{d}\lambda^n(x)=\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^n(\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : e^{-(|x_1|^p+\dots+|x_n|^p)}\geq t\})\, \mathrm{d}t$$

Now I have to apply Cavalieri's principle to $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : e^{-(|x_1|^p+\dots+|x_n|^p)}\geq t\}$.

we have $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : e^{-(|x_1|^p+\dots+|x_n|^p)}\geq t\}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x||_p\leq (\log(t))^{1/p}\}\subset \mathbb{R}\times  \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

For all $y\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ we cut $A_y=\{x\in \mathbb{R} : ||x||_p\leq \log(t)^{1/p}\}$. Now, we have:$$\lambda^n(\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : e^{-(|x_1|^p+\dots+|x_n|^p)}\geq t\})=\int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}\lambda(A_y)\, \mathrm{d}y$$ How can I compute this integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cavalieri, we can write
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-(|x_1|^p+\dots+|x_n|^p)}\mathrm{d}\lambda^n(x)=\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^n(\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x||_p^p \leq \log (1/t)\})\, \mathrm{d}t. $$
Notice that the set we are measuring on the right is empty for $t > 1$ and is just the scaled up unit $L^p$-ball for $0 \leq t \leq 1$,
$$ \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x||_p^p \leq \log (1/t)\} = \log(1/t)^\frac1p \cdot B_p^n. $$
Therefore, by the scaling property of the Lebesgue measure ($\lambda^n (a B) = a^n \lambda^n (B)$), and recalling a [well-known integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Integral_representations) for the Gamma function, we write
$$ \int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^n(\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x||_p^p \leq \log (1/t)\})\, \mathrm{d}t = \lambda^n(B_p^n) \cdot \int_0^1 \log(1/t)^\frac{n}{p} \mathrm d t = \lambda^n (B_p^n) \cdot  \Gamma(1 + n/p). $$
At this point it is reasonable to expect
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-(|x_1|^p+\dots+|x_n|^p)}\mathrm{d}\lambda^n(x) = (2 \Gamma (1 + 1/p))^n $$
which completes the derivation. This essentially is a [generalization of the argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#Gaussian_integrals) used to find the volume of the standard $L^2$-ball in $n$-dimensions, though rather than partitioning the domain of integration explicitly by $n-1$-dimensional spheres and radii we do it instead writing the spheres as level sets.

Comment: Thanks, so we have:$$\int _{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-||x||_p^p}\, \mathrm{d}\lambda^n(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-(|x_1|^p+\dots+|x_n|^p)}\mathrm{d}\lambda^n(x)=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-|x|^p}\, \mathrm{d}x\right)^n=\left(2\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-|x|^p}\, \mathrm{d}x\right)^n=(2\Gamma(1/p+1))^n$$